# findpreference or alternative compatible with Android >3.0 and Android <3.0?

Tags: android, preferences

findpreference() is killing me, i´d like my app runs with a wide range of API, for old and new devices at a time, the problem is that method is deprecated for Android 3.0+, then is needed to use preference fragments for new versions, but preference fragments are not supporter by old versions. Then which is the best way? may be duplicating the settings menu and choosing on runtime by build.VERSION?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I´ve duplicated settings activity, one for Android < 3.0 and other for Android >3.0 using preferenceFragment and it works well.